# Workflow fails during checkout@v4 with Git LFS files error

Tags: git, github, github-actions, git-lfs

I have a GitHub composite action that does checkout of a different repo `MyDevOps` branch `newchkbranch` upon execution. The checkout fails on Git LFS files more often than not (intermittently).

Below is the checkout code in the composite action:

```
Run actions/checkout@v4

  with:

    repository: mybank/MyDevOps

    ref: newchkbranch

    path: D:\Git-Runners\selhostedrun1\_work\myweb-new\myweb-new/MyDevOps

    lfs: true

    token: ***

    ssh-strict: true

    persist-credentials: true

    clean: true

    sparse-checkout-cone-mode: true

    fetch-depth: 1

    fetch-tags: false

    show-progress: true

    submodules: false

    set-safe-directory: true

  env:

    repodirexists: false

    aretoken: ***

Syncing repository: mybank/MyDevOps
```

I tried changing `ssh-strict: false` but that did not help.

Below are the checkout logs:

```
Run actions/checkout@v4

101Syncing repository: mybank/MyDevOps

102Getting Git version info

108Temporarily overriding HOME='D:\Git-Runners\selhostedrun1\_work\_temp\1409ebdf-ecf1-49fe-bf6d-af4ee071807f' before making global git config changes

109Adding repository directory to the temporary git global config as a safe directory

110"C:\Program Files\Git\cmd\git.exe" config --global --add safe.directory D:\Git-Runners\selhostedrun1\_work\myweb-new\myweb-new\MyDevOps

111"C:\Program Files\Git\cmd\git.exe" config --local --get remote.origin.url

112https://github.com/mybank/MyDevOps

113Removing previously created refs, to avoid conflicts

116"C:\Program Files\Git\cmd\git.exe" submodule status

117Cleaning the repository

121Disabling automatic garbage collection

123Setting up auth

129"C:\Program Files\Git\cmd\git.exe" lfs install --local

130Updated Git hooks.

131Git LFS initialized.

132Fetching the repository

136Determining the checkout info

139Fetching LFS objects

Post Checkout / BUILD repo 'mybank/myweb-new'.

3s

Complete job

0s
```

If I expand the failing task during checkout i.e. 139Fetching LFS objects below is the output.

```
Fetching LFS objects

140 "C:\Program Files\Git\cmd\git.exe" lfs fetch origin refs/remotes/origin/newchkbranch

141 fetch: Fetching reference refs/remotes/origin/newchkbranch

142 Could not scan for Git LFS files

143

144 Errors logged to 'D:\Git-Runners\selhostedrun1\_work\myweb-new\myweb-new\MyDevOps\.git\lfs\logs\20231205T105803.4868521.log'.

145 Use `git lfs logs last` to view the log.

146 The process 'C:\Program Files\Git\cmd\git.exe' failed with exit code 2

147 Waiting 20 seconds before trying again

148 "C:\Program Files\Git\cmd\git.exe" lfs fetch origin refs/remotes/origin/newchkbranch

149 fetch: Fetching reference refs/remotes/origin/newchkbranch

150 Could not scan for Git LFS files

151

152 Errors logged to 'D:\Git-Runners\selhostedrun1\_work\myweb-new\myweb-new\MyDevOps\.git\lfs\logs\20231205T105825.6880439.log'.

153 Use `git lfs logs last` to view the log.

154 The process 'C:\Program Files\Git\cmd\git.exe' failed with exit code 2

155 Waiting 20 seconds before trying again

156 "C:\Program Files\Git\cmd\git.exe" lfs fetch origin refs/remotes/origin/newchkbranch

157 fetch: Fetching reference refs/remotes/origin/newchkbranch

158 Could not scan for Git LFS files

159

160 Errors logged to 'D:\Git-Runners\selhostedrun1\_work\myweb-new\myweb-new\MyDevOps\.git\lfs\logs\20231205T105848.5886801.log'.

161 Use `git lfs logs last` to view the log.

162 Error: The process 'C:\Program Files\Git\cmd\git.exe' failed with exit code 2

Post Checkout / BUILD repo 'mmctech/myweb-new'.

3s

Complete job

0s
```

Below are the git logs `.git/lfs/logs`:

```
git-lfs/3.3.0 (GitHub; windows amd64; go 1.19.3; git 77deabdf)

git version 2.40.0.windows.1

 

$ git-lfs fetch origin refs/remotes/origin/newchkbranch

fetch: Fetching reference refs/remotes/origin/newchkbranch

Could not scan for Git LFS files

 

missing object: df86f077dc27c90be894bb45a5b2a129c10c2096

 

Current time in UTC:

2023-12-06 03:08:18

 

Environment:

LocalWorkingDir=D:\Git-Runners\selhostedrun1\_work\myweb-new\myweb-new\MyDevOps

LocalGitDir=D:\Git-Runners\selhostedrun1\_work\myweb-new\myweb-new\MyDevOps\.git

LocalGitStorageDir=D:\Git-Runners\selhostedrun1\_work\myweb-new\myweb-new\MyDevOps\.git

LocalMediaDir=D:\Git-Runners\selhostedrun1\_work\myweb-new\myweb-new\MyDevOps\.git\lfs\objects

LocalReferenceDirs=

TempDir=D:\Git-Runners\selhostedrun1\_work\myweb-new\myweb-new\MyDevOps\.git\lfs\tmp

ConcurrentTransfers=8

TusTransfers=false

BasicTransfersOnly=false

SkipDownloadErrors=false

FetchRecentAlways=false

FetchRecentRefsDays=7

FetchRecentCommitsDays=0

FetchRecentRefsIncludeRemotes=true

PruneOffsetDays=3

PruneVerifyRemoteAlways=false

PruneRemoteName=origin

LfsStorageDir=D:\Git-Runners\selhostedrun1\_work\myweb-new\myweb-new\MyDevOps\.git\lfs

AccessDownload=none

AccessUpload=none

DownloadTransfers=basic,lfs-standalone-file,ssh

UploadTransfers=basic,lfs-standalone-file,ssh

GIT_EXEC_PATH=C:/Program Files/Git/mingw64/libexec/git-core

GIT_HTTP_USER_AGENT=git/2.40.0 (github-actions-checkout)

GIT_TERMINAL_PROMPT=0

 

Client IP addresses:

10.23.145.45

172.17.12.118
```

I was able to replicate the issue using command line like below:

```
git lfs install --skip-smudge

Updated Git hooks.

Git LFS initialized.


git lfs update

Updated Git hooks.

git lfs fetch

fetch: Fetching reference HEAD

Could not scan for Git LFS files

Errors logged to 'D:\Git-Runners\selhostedrun1\_work\myweb-new\myweb-new\MyDevOps\.git\lfs\logs\20231205T214051.3089074.log'.

Use `git lfs logs last` to view the log.
```

If I change the repo branch  `newchkbranch` to something else the checkout issue goes away.

We can also be sure that the issue is not due to network issues as changing the branch resolves the error.

Can you please suggest a solution or workaround?

Comment: You'll need to include the logs, which you should be able to acquire from `.git/lfs/logs` or `git lfs logs last`.  Without those, nobody's going to be able to help you.

Comment: @bk2204 i updated the original post with the requested log.